# Fix imports in transformAsync in babel

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, babeljs, babel-loader

I'm trying to server-render React.js code that is hosted in cloud storage.

Currently, there are 2 files: `App.tsx` and `App2.tsx`, both stored in the cloud. `App.tsx` imports a component from `App2.tsx`.

On the server, I want to fetch both those files and use the renderToString function on `react-dom/server` to statically generate the component.

Currently, I have this code:

```js
let data = await axios.get(
  "FILE_URL/App.tsx",
);
const tsxCode = data.data;

const transpiledCode = await transformAsync(tsxCode, {
  filename: "App.tsx",
  presets: [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
  ],
});
const App = eval(transpiledCode.code);
const html = renderToString(<App/>);
```

The above code throws an error at the line at this line `const App = eval(transpiledCode.code);`. The error message is: `Cannot find module './App2'` (obviously).

I'm wondering if there is a way that I can fetch App2.tsx file from object storage and embed it into App.tsx somehow.